# How to initialize a class inside a Java annotation?

Tags: java, annotations, initialization

We have a class which we need to pass into parameter of annotation but want to initialize it before passing

```
public final class StandardAnalyzer extends StopwordAnalyzerBase {

public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_TOKEN_LENGTH = 255;
private int maxTokenLength;
private final boolean replaceInvalidAcronym;
public static final Set<?> STOP_WORDS_SET;

public StandardAnalyzer(Version matchVersion, Set<?> stopWords) {

}
```

Following is annotation:

```
 @Fields({ @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.NO, analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = StandardAnalyzer.class)
```

In @Analyzer(impl = StandardAnalyzer <- I want to pass arguments i.e StandardAnalyzer(Version, stopwords) and i have tried using new but failed.

Following is annotation details for Analyzer:

```
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = {ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})
@Documented
public @interface Analyzer {
  public Class<?> impl() default void.class; <--- Here is where i want to pass
  public String definition() default "";
}
```

Is there any way out to initialize class before passing in annotation?

Comment: You don't initialize a *class*. You *instantiate* it. That is, you create an instance (an object) and initialize the *instance*. So if what you pass is a class object rather than the true object, it cannot be initialized. How about passing an object rather than a class? Do you know what the parameters are at compile time?

Comment: Yes parameters are there i.e Version.LUCENE_32, Collections.EMPTY_SET

Comment: You have to annotate your class with your *Analyzer* annotation. Within this annotation you define the parameters to describe the more special analyzer class. Then, you can access those parameters via the annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the types that can be given to an annotation are restricted to primitives, String, Class, enums, annotations, and arrays of the preceding types. Thus you can't provide a set of stop words here, for instance. What you're referencing here is a constructor and a constructor will create instances. But what you can do is to provide the constructor parameters as a class:

```
public static class MyAnalyzer extends StandardAnalyzer {
  public MyAnalyzer() { super(Version.LUCENE_32, Collections.EMPTY_SET); }
}
@Fields({ @Field(analyzer = @Analyzer(impl = MyAnalyzer.class) })
```

Depending on your coding rules there might be a problem with this very approach that there are inner classes are mixed with methods. So maybe you might feel better with collecting that kind of classes somewhere. Another drawback is that the classes need to public to actually have a public constructor.